# If Else - Else is not work properly in Java Netbeans

Tags: java, netbeans

i want to ask help. My else in if-else is not work like what i want.
If condition is working properly but when i do else for test, it's not working without any feedback cause i made JOptionPane.show.Message in else.

```
private void BtnMasukActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
    try {
        sql = "SELECT * FROM kasir WHERE username='" + TxtUser.getText() + "' AND password='" + TxtPass.getText() + "'";
        try {
            rs = stm.executeQuery(sql);
        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(login.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        try {
            while (rs.next()) {
                setNama(rs.getString("nama_kasir"));
                setHak(rs.getString("hak_akses"));
                if (TxtUser.getText().equals(rs.getString("username")) && TxtPass.getText().equals(rs.getString("password"))) {
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Anda Berhasil Login");
                    this.dispose();
                    new home().setVisible(true);
                } else {
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Maaf, Username atau Password Anda Salah");
                }
                break;
            }
        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(login.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (HeadlessException e) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, e.getMessage());
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(login.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    } catch (HeadlessException e) {

    }
}
```

Comment: What is the object on which you are calling `dispose()` ?

Comment: iam calling another jframe = home, so i dispose() login jframe or simply this jframe

Comment: Your query only returns data if username and password (in cleartext, dont do that!) match. So why do you check that again in the ``if``?

Comment: Is if statement executing or are you getting any syntax error ?

Comment: Your while loop is guaranteed to `break` after the first call. Is that intended?

Comment: if statement execute properly & without syntax error. iam still don't know about using while or something else

Comment: Unrelated: variable names should go camelCase - not TxtUser. It is also super bad practice to directly access your database from an UI event listener. Seriously: you want to decouple such things.

Comment: The thing is that i can do simple login with ( TxtUser.equals("admin").... ) properly with if - else on it

Comment: Unrelated:  if you catch a `HeadlessException`, you attempt to show a dialog, which will cause a `HeadlessException`!

Answer (score 0):

This is a **very very bad practice**

```
 "SELECT * FROM kasir WHERE username='" + TxtUser.getText() + "' AND password='" + TxtPass.getText() + "'";
```

Because anyone can injecti a sql. Check [this image](http://bobby-tables.com/). Use `prepared statements` instead.

Answering your question. First the query you are executing is searching for USER and PASSWORD. So if you set a wrong password it will return nothing.

```
if (!resultSet.isBeforeFirst() ) {    
System.out.println("USer not found, or incorrect password");
 } else
{
           while (rs.next()) {
                setNama(rs.getString("nama_kasir"));
                setHak(rs.getString("hak_akses"));
                if (TxtUser.getText().equals(rs.getString("username")) && TxtPass.getText().equals(rs.getString("password"))) {
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Anda Berhasil Login");
                    this.dispose();
                    new home().setVisible(true);
                } 
                break;
            }
}
```

Answer (score -2):

Just now i tried this method & it's working, but how to take username to display on next frame?

```
 private void BtnMasukActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
    try{

        ResultSet result = stm.executeQuery("select * from kasir where username='" +TxtUser.getText()+"';");           


        if(result.next()){

            if(TxtPass.getText().equals(result.getString("password"))){

                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Login Berhasil");
                this.dispose();
                new home().show();

            }else{

                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Password Salah");
                TxtPass.setText("");
                TxtUser.requestFocus();
            }
        }else{

            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "User Tidak Ditemukan");
            TxtUser.setText("");
            TxtPass.setText("");
            TxtUser.requestFocus();
        }

    }catch(HeadlessException | ClassNotFoundException | SQLException e){
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Gagal");
    }
}
```

Comment: What is this now? IS this the correct answer of your question? If not, think about whether it makes sense to add a new question as an answer...